# Determine whether the differential operator is compact in the following cases

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, compactness, compact-operators

Given the differential operator $\displaystyle Tx(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}$, I need to determine (and be able to justify) whether it is compact in the following three cases:

1. $T: C^{1}[0,1]\mapsto C[0,1]$
2. $T: C^{2}[0,1]\mapsto C^{1}[0,1]$
3. $T: C^{2}[0,1]\mapsto C[0,1]$.

Although ideally I'd like to see full solutions on all of these - I'm trying to teach myself, and oftentimes the best way for me to do so is to dissect solutions and work backwards.

However, I suppose I could live knowing if the answer is yes or no for all three, and in detail how to do one of them, if of course, seeing how to do one of them would, in fact, help me do the other ones.

What I know about compact operators is the following: I know that they map bounded sets into compact sets (although I've also heard pre-compact sets; not sure 100% if that's true, though). I know that the image of a bounded sequence under a compact operator has a convergent subsequence.

Then, I thought perhaps I could use the Arzela-Ascoli Theorem (Let $X$ be a compact metric space and $\{f_{n}\}$ a uniformly bounded equicontinuous sequence of real-valued functions on $X$. Then $\{f_{n}\}$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on $X$ to a continuous function $f$ on $X$) to help me, but I'm not sure how.

I've also heard a bit about weakly-convergent/strongly-convergent, although I don't think I have quite as good a handle on what that means as I should have.

On the other hand, what I have learned about the differential operator from my own reading isn't terribly helpful, because I've only ever seen it used in $L^{2}[a,b]$, not in $C^{n}[a,b]$ so I'm not sure how to apply it here.

I understand there's a lot going on in this question, but I am extremely clueless about this, need to know it, and would be so incredibly grateful if someone would please humour me and share with me this knowledge. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $1$, start with any bounded sequence $\{ f_n \}$ in $C[0,1]$ that has no convergent subsequence. Then $F_n\int_{0}^{x}f_n(t)dt$ gives you a bounded sequence $\{ F_n \} \subset C^1[0,1]$ whose image under $T$ is $\{ f_n \}$.

For $2$, the same technique holds. Start with a bounded sequence in $C^1[0,1]$ with no convergent subsequence, and integrate.

For $3$, a bounded sequence $\{ f_n \} \subset C^2[0,1]$ has uniformly bounded first and second derivatives, and is mapped by $T$ to a sequence $\{ f_n' \}$ of bounded functions in $C[0,1]$ with uniformly bounded derivatives, which is an equicontinuous subset of $C[0,1]$. Apply Arzela-Ascoli.

Comment: for 2, if I can exhibit a Cauchy sequence in $C^{1}[0,1]$ whose limit is not in $C^{1}[0,1]$ (since $C^{1}[0,1]$ is not complete with respect to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{\infty}$), would this suffice for showing a bounded sequence in $C^{1}[0,1]$ with no convergent subsequence?

Comment: @JessyCat : For (2), take the sequence from (1) and integrate it.

Comment: so I can choose $\{ f_{n}\} = \{ x^{n} \}$ for (1), and then use $\{f_{n}\} = \{ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \}$ for (2)?

Comment: @JessyCat : Sorry, integrate one more time. $\{ \frac{x^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)} \}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. This sequence is bounded in $C^2[0,1]$ because the function, first derivative and second derivative are uniformly bounded. The image under $\frac{d}{dx}$ is $\{ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \}$ which is uniformly bounded with uniformly bounded derivative, but does not converge in $C^1$ because no subsequence of the derivative sequence converges in $C[0,1]$.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with showing the algebra for $\{ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\}$ not having a convergent subsequence. For $\{x^{n}\}$ it was pretty easy, and I could show that $||f_{2n}-f_{n}|| \geq \frac{1}{4}$, so it didn't have any subsequence that was Cauchy. Is there any trick to showing it for $\{ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \}$?

Comment: @JessyCat : In order for $\{ \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \}$ to converge in $C^1[0,1]$, you must have this sequence converge in $C[0,1]$ and its derivative $\{ x^{n} \}$ converge in $C[0,1]$. And the same is true for any subsequence.

Comment: so basically, by showing that $\{x^{n}\}$ did not converge in $C[0,1]$, we showed enough?

Comment: @JessyCat : Yes, and no subsequence converges.

Comment: cool. And so I posted a whole other question for nothing...groovy. It's always better though when things turn out simpler than you thought they'd be. Thanks!

Comment: sorry to bug you again, but the wording on what you said for (3) is a little weird. What do you mean "the imagine of a bounded sequence $\{f_{n}\} \subset C^{2}[0,1]$"? Do you mean "the image of a bounded sequence" or do you mean "imagine a bounded sequence"?