# Compactness of Differential Operator between Sobolev and $L^p$-spaces

Tags: operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, differential, compact-operators, arzela-ascoli

I was wondering under which conditions the (weak) differential operator $D: W^{k,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^p(\Omega)$, $u \mapsto Du$ from a Sobolev space into the underlying $L^p$-space  (on some open subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$) is compact.

My "idea": For the classical differentiable case, i.e. $D:C^m(\Omega)\rightarrow C(\Omega)$, one can use [Arzela-Ascoli](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786369/determine-whether-the-differential-operator-is-compact-in-the-following-cases) to prove that $D$ is compact iff $m\geq 2$. And for $\gamma:=k-\frac{n}{p}>m+\alpha$, the [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) tells us that $W^{k,p}(\Omega)\subset C^{m,\alpha}(\Omega)$. So for sufficiently big $p$ and $k$, one would have that $D:W^{k,p}(\Omega)\rightarrow C(\Omega)$ is compact... however, this compactness is only given with respect to the topology of uniform convergence, not w.r.t. the $L^p$-norm.

Comment: $D$ maps continuously into $W^{k-1,p}$ which is compactly embedded into $L^p$ for $k>1$ (and $\Omega$ bounded with Lipschitz boundary).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ has **finite measure**, uniform convergence implies $L^p$-convergence: Assume that $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset C(\Omega)$ converges against $f\in C(\Omega)$ w.r.t $\|\cdot\|_\infty$, then:

$$\left(\int\limits_\Omega |f(x)-f_n(x)|^p dx\right)^{1/p} \leq \|f-f_n\|_\infty\cdot \mu(\Omega)^{1/p}$$